# Fitting a mesh and a drawing together

Tags: algorithm, geometry, drawing, computational-geometry, mesh

Suppose you're trying to render a user's freehand drawings using a 2D triangular mesh. Start with a plain regular mesh of triangles and color their edges to match the drawing as closely as possible. To improve the results, you can move the vertices of the mesh slightly, but keep them within a certain distance of where they would be in a regular mesh so the mesh doesn't become a mess. Let's say that 1/4 of the length of an edge is a fair distance, giving the vertices room to move while keeping them out of each other's personal space.

Here is a hand-made representation of roughly what we're trying to do. Since the drawing is coming freehand from the user, it's a series of line segments taken from mouse movements.

[image: User draws a curve, mesh is adjusted toward curve, curve is fitted to the edges of the mesh]

The regular mesh is slightly distorted to allow the user's drawing to be better represented by the edges of the mesh. Unfortunately the end result looks quite bad, but perhaps we could have somehow distorted the drawing to better fit the mesh, and the combination of the two distortions would have created something far more recognizable as the original drawing.

The important thing is to preserve angles, so if the user draws a 90-degree corner it ends up looking close to a 90-degree corner, and if the user draws a straight line it doesn't end up looking like a zigzag. Aside from that, there's no reason why we shouldn't change the drawing in other ways, like translating it, scaling it and so on, because we don't need to exactly preserve distances.

One tricky test case is a perfectly vertical line. The triangular mesh in the image above can easily handle horizontal lines, but a naive approach would turn a vertical line into a jagged mess. The best technique seems to be to horizontally translate the line until it passes through each horizontal edge alternating between 1/4 and 3/4 of the way along the edge. That way we can nudge the vertices to the left or right by 1/4 and get a perfect vertical line. That's obvious to a person, but how can an algorithm be made to see that? It involves moving the line further away from vertices, which is the opposite of what we usually want.

Is there some trick to doing this? Does anyone know of a simple algorithm that gives excellent results?